# Product of binomial Coefficients involving limit n tends to infinity

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Find

$$A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\binom{n}{0} \binom{n}{1} \binom{n}{2}\cdots \binom{n}{n}\right)^{1/((n)(n+1))}$$

What I did is convert the product of $\binom{n}{k}$ into

$$\prod_{k=0}^{ k=n} \prod_{r=1}^{r=k}\frac {n-k+r}r$$
I am unable to solve it further, so please provide the solution to this problem

Comment: I have "latexified" your text. Please check that all has been done correctly.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yeah its perfect

Comment: Hint : $\ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b)$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are positive

Comment: @G.Fougeron: I tried taking ln ..but that did not help me much.. If you can provide me solution it will be great

Comment: ... but there, they don't find $1/2$ but $\sqrt{e} \approx  1.6487$ as the limit... ?!

Comment: @JeanMarie: e^1/2 is correct ..I mistaken answer as 1/2 it was ln(A)= 0.5

Comment: It is coherent with the $2$ that I found for the arithmetical limit...

Answer (score 1):

A first result is that the limit, provided it exists, is $\le 2$.

Indeed, one recognizes in the red part here:

$$\left(\color{red}{\left(\binom{n}{0} \binom{n}{1} \binom{n}{2}\cdots \binom{n}{n}\right)^{1/(n+1)}}\right)^{1/n}$$

the geometrical mean of the $n+1$ terms $\binom{n}{k}$
( where $k=0,1,2...n$) that subsequently will be taken at the power $1/n$.

This geometrical mean is less than the associated arithmetical mean:

$$\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots \binom{n}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}2^n$$

Taking the power $1/n$ of this result, we get $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/n}}2$ whose limit is $2$.

(Thanks to @saulspatz for spotting an error of mine).

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but it seems to me that the arithmetic mean should be $$\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^{1/n}$$

Comment: @saulspatz You are perfectly right. It shouldn't impair the final result...

Comment: @JeanMarie: I got your method but the answer given is 1/2 .. I am unable to understand but the solution given to me in my book involves integration as a limit of sum

Comment: @VipulJain Why not edit your question to show the solution, and indicate where you lose the thread?